# Unit Testing with Promises and Spies

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise, sinon

I have the following files:-

**target.js**

```
var target = function(repository, logger) {

    return {
        addTarget : function(target) {
            repository.add(target).then(
                function (newTarget) {
                    console.log("added");
                    logger.info("added");
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log("error");
                    logger.info("error");
                }
            );
        }
    };
};

module.exports = target;
```

**targetTest.js**

```
var chai = require("chai"),
    expect = chai.expect,
    sinon = require("sinon"),
    Promise = require("bluebird"),
    baseTarget = require("../target");

describe("target", function(){
    it("should log error when it occurs", function() {
        var mockRepository = {
            add : sinon.stub().returns(Promise.reject(new Error()))
        };

        var mockLogger = {
            info : sinon.spy()
        };

        var target = baseTarget(mockRepository, mockLogger);

        target.addTarget("target");

        expect(mockLogger.info.calledWith("error")).to.be.true;
    });
});
```

The issue I have is that `expect(mockLogger.info.calledWith("error")).to.be.true;` returns `false` because `add` method on the repository is async and so hasn't executed yet. Is there a pattern for doing this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really more of a question about 'how Promises work' than how they work within test frameworks - the answer to which is that their behaviour remains exactly the same.

> Is there a pattern for doing this properly.

It is not so much a pattern as it is what Promises are built to do. Each success handler of a `then` is executed in sequence on success of the last. In your code we can return the Promise created by calling `repository#add` as you would if you wanted to use its result or perform some external dependent operation outside of `addTarget`:

```
addTarget: function (target) {
    return repository
//  ^^^^^^
        .add(target)
        .then(function (newTarget) {
            console.log("added");
            logger.info("added");
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("error");
            logger.info("error");
        });
}
```

Then place your expectation inside a `then` that will be executed on success of all members of the Promise chain created in `addTarget`:

```
target.addTarget("target").then(function () {
    expect(mockLogger.info.calledWith("error")).to.be.true;
    cb();
});
```

**Asynchronous Tests**

You will notice in the example above that there is also a call to a function `cb`. Due to your test being asynchronous you need to 'tell' the test framework when the test has completed. This is most often done by declaring your `it` function with a parameter, from which the framework will infer that the test is asynchronous and pass in a callback:

```
describe("target", function () {
    it("should log error when it occurs", function (cb) {
                                                // ^^^^
    });
});
```